# Cant get connexion using MongoTor

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, tornado

I was trying to change my code to make it asynchronous using [MongoTor](https://github.com/marcelnicolay/mongotor)

Here is my simple code:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property 
    def db(self):
        if not hasattr(self,"_db"):
            _db = Database.connect('localhost:27017', 'essog')
            return _db
    @property
    def fs(self):
        if not hasattr(BaseHandler,"_fs"):
            _fs = gridfs.GridFS(self.db)
            return _fs


class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def post(self):
        email = self.get_argument("email")
        password = self.get_argument("pass1")
        try:
            search = yield tornado.gen.Task(self.db.users.find, {"prs.mail":email})
            ....
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1043, in _stack_context_handle_exception
raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1162, in wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 122, in wrapper
runner.run()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 365, in run
yielded = self.gen.send(next)
File "G:\Mon projet\essog\handlers.py", line 92, in post
search = yield tornado.gen.Task(self.db.users.find, {"prs.mail":email})
File "G:\Mon projet\essog\handlers.py", line 62, in db
_db = Database.connect('localhost:27017', 'essog')
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mongotor\database.py", line 131, in connect
database.init(addresses, dbname, read_preference, **kwargs)
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mongotor\database.py", line 62, in init
ioloop_is_running = IOLoop.instance().running()
 AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'running'
 ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /login (::1) 3.00ms
```

Here is another question, how do I make `distinct` in this case?

Here is what worked in **blocking mode**:

```
search = self.db.users.find({"prs.mail":email}).distinct("prs.mail")[0]
```

Update:

It seems that this error happens when there is no Tornado running! It's the same error raised when using only the module in console.

> test = Database.connect("localhost:27017", "essog")
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 test = Database.connect("localhost:27017", "essog")
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongotor-0.0.10-py2.7.egg\mongotor\database.pyc
>   in connect(cls, addresses, dbname, read_preference, **kwargs)
>       131 
>       132         database = Database()
>   --> 133         database.init(addresses, dbname, read_preference, **kwargs)
>       134 
>       135         return database
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongotor-0.0.10-py2.7.egg\mongotor\database.pyc
>   in init(self, addresses, dbname, read_preference, **kwargs)
>        60             self._nodes.append(node)
>        61 
>   ---> 62         ioloop_is_running = IOLoop.instance().running()
>        63         self._config_nodes(callback=partial(self._on_config_node,
>   ioloop_is_running))
>        64
>
> AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'running'

Comment: does it because in asynchronous i cant use inheritence to make the connexion open all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the asnwer:

1. right now, Tornado 2.4post1 has removed running(), so to use the actual MongoTor, use tornado 2.4

Edit: tornado and mongotor works better now, with their latest version.

1. [using distinct](https://github.com/marcelnicolay/mongotor/issues/20):

   ```
   distinc_uuids = yield gen.Task(db.collection_test.find({"param":'shouldbeparam1'}).distinct, 'uuid')
   ```

Comment: sorry, dident updated the answer, now the latests mongotor works